# Financial chart component for C#

Tags: c#, charts, plot

I am in need of a component for drawing financial charts with the following features for my application:

1. Live plotting.
2. OHLC Chart, candlestick chart and previous day close chart.
3. Various Analysis studies.
4. Easy distribution with designing tools.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using winforms, WPF, something else ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing *Windows Forms* or web applications, the open-source [Zedgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) is a good solution. You can see examples of OHLC and candlestick charts [here](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index1369.html?title=Bar_Charts). There is also sufficient designer support for incorporating Zedgraph graph controls into your forms.

.NET Framework 4.0 also contains [Windows Forms charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx) out-of-the-box, although Zedgraph is more powerful.

[WPF charting](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) is available in the WPF Toolkit on Codeplex. It is even less complete than its *Windows Forms* correspondent, but on WPF it should at least be a decent open-source alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts or Highstock - http://www.highcharts.com/

Highcharts or Highstock are used for web development though. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms not web. Paid component is also fine...